# How to efficiently calculate the top permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a 2D array of letters, each with a score.  For example:

```
J-95 O-90 H-92 N-99
I-91 0-89 L-55
1-80
T-55
```

From the above array, I would like to get a list of the top 20 or so permutations (by score)  quickly.  In the above example, the list would be:

```
JOHN
IOHN
J0HN
I0HN
... etc
```

I'm currently doing this in a recursive function -- but it is slower than I'd like.  Is there any good way to get a top N list quickly?  My code is C++ (if there are good library suggestions).

Thanks

### Edit:

I solved this using a combination of Sneftel and Ethan's answers.  I used a pruning function to reduce the possible characters based on the weights, then calculated the permutations from that.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/ ?

Comment: Can you provide the source code? Also one good way to make it faster, don't use recursion, use a loop.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I'm not sure how it would work because the letters have a particular order.  For example, The #2 response needs to be IOHN rather than JIHN, even though JIHN has a higher score than IOHN.

Comment: Why isn't #2 `J0HN`? And why does `IOHN` appear twice?

Comment: It doesn't look like you really want permutations. Permutations imply you can reorder the elements. What you want is the top 20 maximally-scoring elements of the cartesian product of `"JI1T"`, `"O0"`, `"HL"`, and `"N"`.

Comment: How long are the lists of options for each position expected to be?

Comment: I think you're right, I do need the cartesian product of those sets.  I wonder if there's an efficient way of getting the top list without iterating over everything.  They could be up to 36 spots for each position and there could be up to 11 or so positions.  As you can imagine, in some cases there are many millions of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is actually NP-complete; it is a form of the "Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem" (MCKP).

A simple approach which may work out for you is to generate combinations from the top 1 letter in each slot, then the top 2 letters in each slot, then the top 3, etc., and stop once two iterations in a row produce the same top 20 scores. This isn't guaranteed to be any more efficient than a brute force search, but it's simple to implement and will work well for the "general" case.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to sort your candidates. It takes O(nlgn) time.

```
N-99 J-95 H-92 I-91 O-90 0-89 1-80 L-55 T-55
```

---

Secondly, depending on how many best scores you need, you choose the top n number of characters to do the permutation.

```
(n)*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) / (1 * 2 * 3 * 4) >= m.
```

n is the number of candidates you choose. m is the number of best scores you need. For example, if you need 20 best scores, you only do set of 7 characters. Probably the problem you face is that you do the permutation with all candidates while it is a waste to do it with some very low candidates.

---

Third step is get all the permutations you need, then sort it and print.

Answer (score 1):

for examples of perm code rosetta code has some great examples in many languages [this is in c++](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#C.2B.2B). Once you get your permutations code working you can make a return biggestscore function and maybe use a map to map words to scores.

```
    char** permutations(char *word, int len){
        ... //the perm code
    }
    //returns array of cstrings permutations

    char** returnBiggestScore(char **permutations, int len){
        ...// your score logic goes here
    }
    //would return the top five say,
```

In your main program you can do something like this:

```
returnBiggestScores(permutations("hello"));
```

How you code your return biggest score is up to you, but I suggest using a map object,
that way you can check for the score of any arbitrary letter in constant time like so:

```
score['B']; //fast and convinient returns score value for key 'B'
```